# how can i sumifs from another dataframe using R?

Tags: r

Currently I have two data frames that are imported from excel files and the data frames details are as follows:

combined_df:(Note: there are approx 300,000 policies no. and also there are like 20 variables to extract (e.g. x , y, z , f , s , d , e , ...)

```
Policy No.    x     y    z    f
12203         0     0    0    0
123123        0     0    0    0
12121         0     0    0    0
```

data_df:

```
Policy No.    Reference No.     Local Currency     Foreign Currency     Date
12203             x                  10                  20             01/2022
12203             y                  6                   12             02/2022
12203             x                 100                  200            10/2022
12121             x                 7                    14             08/2022
12121             f                 80                   160            12/2022
```

I would like to sumifs the "local currency" column from the data_df based on the criteria of the policy no. and also the respective reference no.

output_df:

```
Policy No.    x     y    z    f
12203         110   6    0    0
123123        0     0    0    0
12121         7     0    0    80
```

I have thought of looping through the policy no. in the combined_df, but it is not efficient and takes very long.

Answer (score 1):

When combining data from multiple sources, it's often helpful to reshape your data longer. I do that with the first table, then remove the redundant `value` column. Now we can join that to the total `Local.Currency` for each `Policy_no`/`Reference_no` combination. For final cleanup, I replace the NAs with 0s and then reshape wide to be like `output_df`.

```
library(tidyverse)
a |>
  pivot_longer(-Policy_no, names_to = "Reference_no") |>
  select(-value) |>
  left_join(b |>
              count(Policy_no, Reference_no, wt = Local.Currency)) |>
  replace_na(list(n = 0)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Reference_no, values_from = n)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Policy_no     x     y     z     f
      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     12203   110     6     0     0
2    123123     0     0     0     0
3     12121     7     0     0    80
```

---

Data

```
a <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Policy_no, ~x, ~y, ~z, ~f,
      12203L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
     123123L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
      12121L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
  )


b <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Policy_no, ~Reference_no, ~Local.Currency, ~Foreign.Currency,     ~Date,
      12203L,           "x",             10L,               20L, "01/2022",
      12203L,           "y",              6L,               12L, "02/2022",
      12203L,           "x",            100L,              200L, "10/2022",
      12121L,           "x",              7L,               14L, "08/2022",
      12121L,           "f",             80L,              160L, "12/2022"
  )
```